Complete regex to validate German license plates?
TL;DR: German license plates are complicated, let's swarm on an "as complete as possible" regex.

I was looking on multiple sources for a "complete" regex to validate German license plates. I found multiple candidates, but all are lacking in some regard.
Candidate A
In this previous question the correct answer was:
^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}-[a-zA-Z]{1,2} \d{1,4}$

Candidate B
I've commonly seen this regex from the etl-tools website:
^[A-ZÄÖÜ]{1,3}\-[ ]{0,1}[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{1,4}[H]{0,1}

which is already better but is not quite right as well and seems out of date (missing optional E on the end)
Requirements I was able to gather

First Group (region code)

1-3 uppercase letters including ÄÖÜ, but excluding ß
OR a 0 for diplomats
CAN be one of the allowed configurations: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_aller_deutschen_Kfz-Kennzeichen_mit_einer_Gebietseinteilung


A hyphon symbol standing in for the stickers on the plate
Second group (letters)

This time only A-Z
either 1 or 2 of these letters for normal license plates
0-2 of these letters for special plates, like public offices


Third group (numbers)

The numbers 0-9
1-4 of these numbers
NOT leading with 0


Fourth group (special plates)

Either E or H, E indicating an electric vehicle, H indicating a historic one


I found some sources saying that it could only be eight characters in total (unclear whether it applies to groups 1-3 or 1-4)

My proposed solution
^([A-Z0ÄÖÜ]{1,3})-([A-Z]{0,2})([1-9][0-9]{0,3})([HE]?)$

Shortcomings of proposed solution

Does not validate for total length
Does not support several police formats:

BW 6-1234


Does not support some federal formats:

BD 15-1234


Probably a lot more, please comment them and help improve the regex


Just a general thought: it might make sense to have different expressions for normal and special plates to reduce the number of potentially incorrect combinations.

This would probably be the relevant source of truth for normal plates: https://bmdv.bund.de/SharedDocs/DE/Artikel/StV/Strassenverkehr/ueberblick-ueber-die-kraftfahrzeugkennzeichen.html (note that e.g. the number can start with "0")

It's best to add all the possible sample inputs in your question.

"Probably a lot more, please comment them and help improve the regex": this makes your question off-topic. It should be precise in what is considered a correct answer and what not.

So you want to check on the correct format only, but not for actual validity of the data, correct? (Because FOO XY 123 would be valid in format, but a city/region code FOO does not exist.)

Multiple patterns can be simply added up using |. Such as:
^([A-Z0ÄÖÜ]{1,3})([A-Z]{0,2})([1-9][0-9]{0,3})([HE]?)$|^([A-Z0ÄÖÜ]{1,3})\s([1-9][0-9]{0,3})-([1-9][0-9]{0,3})$


Please note that () is a capture group. If you don't need capture groups, you can use non-capture groups (?:) instead (e.g., (?:[A-Z0ÄÖÜ]{1,3})) or completely remove it.

The regex pattern you're looking for could be simple. But, I don't have enough info about German license plates.


